# Sidebar menu with submenu items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a sidebar with categories for my website so when a user hovers over an item on the sidebar, an additional sub-menu opens up to the right, possibly even a sub-sub-menu. A perfect working example of what I am trying to create can be found on the top left of http://www.ebay.com.

My question is, what is the best way to go about creating this menu? Jquery? CSS/HTML only? Should I use UL + LI elements to create the menu or just divs like the ones below?  I was thinking something along the lines of having a hiddin sub-menu div within the initial div that I would 'show' on hover, using JQuery, is that a pretty good solution?

I appreciate any suggestions or recommendations on a good way to do this.

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="menu-item">Cars > (Ford, Chevy, VW)</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Food > (Fruits, Burgers, Veggies)</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Sports > (Soccer, Football, Basketball)</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Movies > (Action, Comedy, Horror) </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: use jquery/js for this because only css will make your code big

Comment: like [this](http://sonicradish.com/labs/jGlideMenu/current/static_demo.html) ?

Comment: "what is best way to build a menu"  is hardly an appropriate question here. There are 100's of resources for menu building on web

Comment: Imo: the less js, the better. Only use it when it's neccesary. That will make your page perform better. And secondly, use ul/li, because that is easier to read.

Comment: If you took the time to read my question you would see that it is more specific that 'what is the best way to build a menu'. @charliefl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this can be done with CSS only. The markup shoud look like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Cars
         <ul>
             <li>Ford</li>
             <li>Chevy</li>
             <li>VW</li>
         </ul>    
    </li>
    <li>Food
         <ul>
             <li>Fruits</li>
             <li>Burgers</li>
             <li>Veggies</li>
         </ul>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can find example CSS here: http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/css_drop_down_menu/

Comment: @Somebody is in trouble: What do you mean?

Comment: i am 100% sure that it can be done with js also not with css only

Comment: @PanJanek I would like to show the inner UL on hover of the category, I don't think your example covers that...

Comment: @MHZ: I attached link to example CSS that shows inner UL on hover of outer LI element. It will work in all modern browsers above IE6

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel when there are pre-existing plugins out there.

You should check out superfish. Specifically check out their [vertical menu demo](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample3).